# Why does Xpages app throw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at seemingly random intervals?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse, ibm-domino

We are using HCL Domino 11.0.1 FP7

We have an xpages application which uses Java, used only via web browser. Generally, it works fine.

After a while, perhaps once or twice a week, with no exact pattern, this error is thrown:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (classname)`

The (classname) varies - it's not one particular class causing the problem, but is one of our Java classes as opposed to something built-in.

No design elements have changed, the app hasn't been edited in any way.

'Cleaning' the project (Project -> clean...) from HCL Designer fixes it again.

Can anyone shed any light on why this error might be thrown?

Edit:
Example line:

```
public  AssignmentDAO getModelDAO() {
    return new AssignmentDAO();
}
```

the "return new.. " line threw the error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: How do you load the classes? A simple reproducer might help.

Comment: @stwissel have added the lines to the question - hope that helps ?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError occurs when a compiled class references another class that isn’t on the runtime classpath. Any relation to time http has been up ?
Do you restart the http every night, if not try that if that solves the problem.

Comment: @FredrikNorling thanks for that - It's a client's server so I don't have full control, but I can advise them. Currently I believe they restart the server twice a week: Thursday night and Sunday. Interesting thought re uptime though, thank you.